# i have been using jQuery to parse XML but it doesnt maintain uppercase. Is there a flag im missing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

My understanding is that since it is build for the internet and there is no capitalization that is hardcoded into it, but i was curious if there was a flag i could set to preserve case.

I have a bunch of XML nodes like:

```
<DisplayLabel></DisplayLabel>
<Textbox></Textbox>
<Style></Style>
```

and i was going to just do a simple conversion to pascal case or something, but that wouldnt really get the *L* in *Label* to be uppercased because it doesnt understand it.

Should i use JQUERY, to do this, or something else?  I really have every functionality i want, but the node names are related to JS functions... so as you can tell:

```
window.displaylabel()
```

would be undefined whereas it was wanting to call:

```
window.DisplayLabel()
```

Comment: pretty already asked question....Jquery converts all to lowercase.  No way around it with regular jquery.

Comment: Rooster. do know of an alternate jquery suppliment which would do it?  A specific jquery branch or something?

Comment: It's not really jQuery that's doing the actual parsing. The library just hands the text over to the browser's parser. By default it parses markup as HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery parses strings as *HTML* DOM nodes, which is case-insensitive and normalized to lowercase.

You need `$.parseXML()`, which will parse a string as *XML* DOM nodes.
You can then call `$(node)` to wrap it in a jQuery object.

Comment: so instead of just doing $(doc) do $($.parseXML(doc)) ?

Comment: @Fallenreaper: Exactly.

Comment: As a quick subquestion, how would i get the tag name (without using .get(0).tagName ) because that does all upper case.

Comment: i was thinking $(item).prop("tagName") but i wasnt sure if that did all caps etc.

Comment: The answer is:  nodeName.     item.prop("nodeName") will return the nodes name as it is where as tagName == uppercase of node Name.