# Dynamic tables from xml response jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to create table rows with data from an xml response.

> Here is my success function:

```
 success: function(response) {

            $('id', response).each(function() {

                 const row = $('<tr>');
                 row.append($('<td>').html($(this).find('name').text()));
                 row.append($('<td>').html($(this).find('result').text()));
                 row.append($('<td>').html($(this).find('date').text()));
                 $('#result-list').append(row);


             });
```

> Here is my html:

```
    <table id="result-list" class="table table-striped" style="margin-top:15px;">
 <thead>

  <tr>
     <th scope="col">name</th>
     <th scope="col">result</th>
     <th scope="col">date</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>

</tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is that it appends all the variables in one row. For example it appends all the result variables in the same row. I would like to create a new row for each name,result,date fields.

First name,result,date in row 1. Second name,result,date in row 2 and so on..

Comment: imvain2 is on the right track, add a trailing slash or a closing tag to your row declaration: `const row = $('<tr/>');` or `const row = $('<tr></tr>');`

Comment: I added the closing tag but still having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

So it wasn't about table creation. The problem was that in the xml response i had all the id's wrapped in a Id(uppercase version of the id tag). I didn't know that jquery parsing strings was case-insesitive.

So $.parseXML(response) instead of response solved my problem as stated here : [i have been using jQuery to parse XML but it doesnt maintain uppercase. Is there a flag im missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384034/i-have-been-using-jquery-to-parse-xml-but-it-doesnt-maintain-uppercase-is-there)